# Transiting Sabiha Gökçen Istanbul from the UK for Kazakhstan. Do I need a transit visa as a British citizen?

Tags: transit-visas, uk-citizens, turkey, istanbul

I will be flying from the UK to Kazakhstan via Istanbul's Sabiha Gökçen airport. I'll have an hour layover there, do I need a Turkish transit visa?

I am British and I fly both flights with Pegasus on one ticket.

Comment: What is your citizenship? (nationality?)
Did you buy 1 ticket or did you buy the ticket for each flight seperate?

Comment: British. Both flights with Pegasus

Comment: It doesn't matter whether both flights are on Pegasus. The question was whether both flights are on the same ticket . Many budget carriers only sell point to point tickets and don't do connecting flights

Comment: It's a connecting flight on the same ticket

Answer (score 1):

In your case you won't be legally entering Turkey at all, because you'll be travelling on one ticket all the way to Kazachstan and you will remain "airside" in the airport terminal.

However, in your case you needn't worry at all, because British citizens have anyway visa-free access to Turkey (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Turkey) for up to 90 days, so even if you have to enter Turkey for whatever reasons, you'll be admitted.